# Excel VBA : Code to protect template and remain protected after copying

Tags: excel, vba, templates, copy

I have a template which represents a data table for the days of the week, I want to protect the template for modification (I done that), and when I press the button "Insert a new sheet for the next week", I get a copy of the template but it's not protected like the template.

How can I do That ?

There is my code :

```
Sub Bouton_NewSheet()
Dim NumSemaine As String
NumSemaine = InputBox("Veuillez entrer le numéro de la semaine :", "Insertion d'une feuille vierge")


If NumSemaine <> "" Then
'vérifier si valeur nuémrique
While Not IsNumeric(NumSemaine)
MsgBox "Merci de saisir une valeur numérique", vbExclamation
NumSemaine = InputBox("Veuillez entrer un numéro de semaine", "Insertion d'une feuille vierge")
Wend

Sheets("Template").Visible = True
Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "S" & NumSemaine
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value = "S" & NumSemaine
Sheets("Template").Visible = True
MsgBox "Votre feuille de suivi de stock est pour la semaine N°" & NumSemaine
End If
Sheets("Template").Protect
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: how about `Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Protect` after the line `Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)`?

Comment: Thats working, but Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Protect replace Seets("Template").Protect
Thank You

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the comment correctly, but it should work in either place.